# Accessing a serial connection state within two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-communication

I'm trying to set up another thread that currently checks the status of the object being referenced.

The **main thread** is what runs the program and also handles the serial connection state.

The **second thread** needs to access the connection state to continue sending and receiving commands from the buffer.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  The thread controlling the serial device needs to provide a thread-safe read-only property which remembers the last state that it read.  The other thread can than read that propery whenever it would like.

Here's a simple solution:

```
string lastReadState = "";
object StateLock = new Object();
string State { get { lock(StateLock) { return lastReadState; } } }

// Main thread working away...
lock (StateLock) { lastReadState = ReadCurrentState(); }

// Other thread working away...
string state = State;
```

**Edit** (after seeing the comments)

```
SomeStateClass lastReadState = new StateClass();
object StateLock = new Object();
SomeStateClass State { get { lock(StateLock) { return lastReadState; } } }

// Main thread figures out the new state information at some point...
lock (StateLock) { lastReadState = new StateClass { Prop1 = whatever, ... }; }

// Other thread uses the state
var relevantInfo = State.Prop1;
```

Comment: Hmm... I understand what your saying... but it's still a bit tricky in my circumstance... or maybe its just me. Heres a bit more information:

DeviceConnection Connection is an object tucked away in another class on the main thread that holds the current connection type... in my case its serial, set with the baud rate, etc. Then I have another class that is being run on this main thread as well... however what i've done is the following:

Comment: Constructor ->
Thread currentSong = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateCurrentSongInfo));
currentSong.Start();

Then ->
[STAThread]
private void UpdateCurrentSongInfo

So now UpdateCurrentSongInfo would have to grab the connection state.

Comment: @user436280: Part of your response was cut off.  Maybe you should modify your question instead of putting it in a comment, so others can see it easier.

Comment: So my question now is where do i set the StateLock and the State?

Comment: @user436280: The principle should still apply.  Provide a value (maybe a copy of an existing object) which will only change when the main thread replaces it with the newly updated "current" value.  All other threads access that unbound copy.  It lets you have the real class wherever you need it, while providing a separate class (or instance) for the thread-shared data.

Comment: Awesome... works perfect... however one more problem. 
lock (locker) { Connection.Send(cmd); }

Upon build, it breaks at Connection.Send(cmd);.
It says I need to create a new instance of the object Connection because its null... but when I hover over the property in its debug state there are proper values. Why would it say its null if it has values? I think invoke might be required... not too sure because i'm not 100% as to what invoke will do in this case. Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems that if I continue the program after it warns me... it works... but I'm assuming its not good code... must be missing something.

Comment: @user436280: I'm not sure what's going on, since that's not part of the initial question.  Posting a new question with the correct context may give you the answer you're looking for.